# Solarwinds Network Performance Monitor Service possibly corrupt

Tags: monitoring

I have a laptop running server 2003 with Solar winds software installed. This laptop is used to probe a customers network while we setup a proper server.

When the laptop is powered on and you try to run Solarwinds Network Performance monitor, it freezes until you open Task Manager, end the process, then open Services, stop the service, refresh a couple of times so it shows as stopped, and then restart the service.

Once this is done the Network Performance Monitor works fine, up until the next time the laptop is turned off and/or restarted. I have tried adding a startup script via gpedit but that didn't work. I have tried making a batch file on the desktop to be run before hand but the service just sticks in stopping. I have also tried adding a registry entry to restart the service without success, anyone any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: On the Service itself - have you tried going to the Recovery tab and setting the First, Second and Subsequent failures to "Restart the Service"? Also, you could try to do "Automatic Startup (Delayed)" as it sounds like the service gets hung waiting on a dependency.

Comment: yes I have tried all of that with the same results :-(

Answer (score 0):

Investigate the resources available and performance. You haven't described your setup at all, but I'm guessing that you put the SQL server and the polling engine and the web server all on the same machine. Which is running a 10-year old OS, and is on a laptop with a drive that probably can't push a lot of IOPS. Check the CPU and memory of course, but also check the disk queue. I bet it runs pretty high.

/Edit - And  I am assuming you've checked the Windows Event Viewer and there's no clues in there, right?

Comment: I am not to certain on the setup to be fair, my manager set it up went on holiday as left me to fix the issues, yes the SQL server and the polling engine are on the laptop which only has a 120gb harddrive and 2gb RAM, there is still 76gb of hdd space left available RAM is being used at 40 - 72% I don't think there is a webserver installed @mfinni

Comment: So check the other performance stats. Use perfmon, not task manager.

Comment: using performance monitor, 0 - 100 up the left and line graphs being drawn, avg disk queue length peaks at 28 steady at 0, processor time fluctuating between 48 and 56, mem pages per sec steady at 16 peaking to 20 every 27 seconds

Comment: what's the average of the avg disk queue length?

Comment: The average is showing as 0 flatlining along the bottom with an occasional spike to 28